# How to know the name of the variable containing the max number after Math.max()

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following variables:

```
var num1 = 48;
var num2 = 420;
var num3 = 39;
```

And I want to know the max value, for that I use:

```
var max = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
```

Is there a way to know that num2 was the max number? This example only has 3 variables, but let's say I have 20 or 500. I need to know the max value and its variable name in the most efficient way.

Comment: What if you have 2 different variables with the same maximum value?

Comment: This sound like an XY problem. What are you trying to do, there may be a better way to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Having 500 variables maximum? how do you created?

Comment: @User863 No maximum, N variables.

Comment: @phuzi In that case it doesn't matter, just I want to get the max number and the name of the variable containing that max number. If there are multiple variables with the same maximum value just the first one maybe?

Comment: You could create an object using Shorthand property names `const o = { num1, num2, num3 }`. And then loop through the object and keep track of the key name and the max value: `let maxKey, maxValue= -Infinity; for(const key in o) if(o[key] > maxValue){ maxKey = key; maxValue = o[key] }`

Comment: Why exactly are you interested in variable name? I think you want to choose a branch depending on whether num1 is greatest, or num2, or num3. Use `if...else`.

Comment: You are not epressing your real problem in your question if there is one per se. What's wrong with assigning the max value to a new variable and using it in your code? Why exactly you need to access to the old variables?

Comment: @SalmanA I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to get the result.

Comment: @Redu I minimized the text so as not to ask a too long question, basically what I want is: for N variables, calculate the maximum of those N variables and return the following result: (variable_name, max_value). There will probably be a thousand ways to do it, I just want the most efficient way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot know the variable name because the variable name is not passed into javascript functions, only the values, but you can have a workaround

with arrays:

```js
var numbers = [48,420,39];

const index = numbers.indexOf(Math.max(...numbers))

console.log(`The max value is the ${index+1}nth value in the array`)
```

with objects

```js
var num1 = 48;
var num2 = 420;
var num3 = 39;

var numbers = {num1, num2, num3}

const maxVal = Math.max(...Object.values(numbers))
const key = Object.keys(numbers).find(key => numbers[key] === maxVal)

console.log(key, maxVal)
```

Comment: You can create an object with existing variables: `var numbers = { num1, num2, num3 }`

Comment: @adiga thanks for the tip, yep, now it is more according to the OP's request

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work on my end with objects. Actually, it worked for the first iteration of the loop, but not for the others. I need the code to be inside the loop, any ideas?

Comment: @Cheknov maybe because of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Check the compatibility at the end. You can replace that statement with `Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(numbers))`

Comment: @Cheknov what do you need exactly? What is failing exactly on your side?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `var`, it will get binded to the `window` object. Then you can iterate over `window` object, and get the name of variable.  Also, if you follow same naming convention, like `num1`, `num2` etc, you can use a if condition to check if `num` is present in key or not.

```js
var num1 = 48;
var num2 = 420;
var num3 = 39;

var max = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);

let s = Object.keys(window).filter(key => {
      if (key.includes("num")) {
          return window[key] == max
        }
      });

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## O(n) Solution

```js
function getMaxIndex(nums) {
  let max = -Infinity, maxIndex = -1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] > max) {
      max = nums[i]
      maxIndex = i
    }
  }
  return maxIndex
}

const nums = [48, 420, 39]
let i = getMaxIndex(nums)
console.log(i) // 1, because the index of 420 is 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function getHighestNumber(nums) {
  return nums.reduce((acc, num, index) => {
    if(num > acc.value) {
      acc.value = num;
      acc.index = index;
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, {value: null, index: null});
}

let nums = [48,420,39];
const max = getHighestNumber(nums);

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the values into an array / list, so that you can compare easily in a for loop.
Example:

```
let nums = [48,420,39]; 
let max = Math.max(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2]);
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(nums[i] == max){
        console.log("The largest is num" + i)
    }
}
```

this is the best i could think of.

Comment: or `let max = Math.max(...nums); let indexOfMax = nums.indexOf(max);`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, to use an array / list as well but...isn't there any predefined function that returns the name of the variable or the position of the maximum number?

Comment: as `Math.Max` inside also has some loop... probably better to find max also manually but it will be only 1 loop?

Answer (score 0):

create an array that will hold the variable name and its value
like this:

```
let varAndVal = 
[
  {"varName":"num1",
   "value": 50},
   {"varName":"num2",
   "value": 51},
   {"varName":"num3",
   "value": 52},
]
```

then I would run over the array and find the max value and its name like this:

```
 function getMaxNumAndVarName(arr) {
    let i;
   
    // Initialize maximum element
    let maxVar = arr[0];

    // Traverse array elements 
    // from second and compare
    // every element with current max 
    for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].value > maxVar.value)
            maxVar = arr[i];
    }
     
  return maxVar;
}
```

```js
let varAndVal = [{
    "varName": "num1",
    "value": 50
  },
  {
    "varName": "num2",
    "value": 51
  },
  {
    "varName": "num3",
    "value": 52
  },
]

function getMaxNumAndVarName(arr) {
  let i;

  // Initialize maximum element
  let maxVar = arr[0];

  // Traverse array elements 
  // from second and compare
  // every element with current max 
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].value > maxVar.value)
      maxVar = arr[i];
  }

  return maxVar;
}

console.log(getMaxNumAndVarName(varAndVal));
```

Comment: You don't actually have variables with those names!

Comment: The idea is to create the object **according to the real variables**, and return the name of the that "variable" from the object

Answer (score 0):

Your variables can be properties of an object, members of a function scope or reside in a module.

1. If they are properties of an object including the global/window object you can access them with `Object.keys()` and `.reduce()` to determine the variable with maximum value.

   ```
   var object = { var1: 1
                , var2: 2
                , var3: 3
                },
       maxVar = Object.keys(object).reduce((p,c) => object[p] > object[c] ? p : c);

   console.log(maxVar); // "var3";
   ```

   Or use a `for in` loop.
2. However if you need to define your variables in a function scope
   then you best make your function a constructor and claim your
   variable names like `this.var1 ... this.varN` etc in order to access
   the scope variables from the instantiated object and repeat 1.
3. Put your variables in a module and do like

   ```
   export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const`
   ```

   to be imported in your code like

   ```
   import * as object from "./myModule";
   ```

   and repeat 1.